# Trigger to set time restrictions in MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, time, triggers, restriction

First question here, sorry if the formatting comes out strangely!

I'm currently practising with triggers within databases and I have reached a point where I can't find a way around an issue. I want to set a limit on when a 'client' can book a time slot. I need it so the clients can't book a slot between the hours of 9pm and 9am. In the table for the timeslots I have the 'lesson_time' column which is a TIME data type '00:00:00'. The code below is my current attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TimeBoundaries
BEFORE INSERT ON lessons
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF new.lesson_time > 20:00:00 AND new.lesson_time < 08:00:00
  THEN
  SET MSG='Error: Lesson must start between 8am and 8pm!'; 
  END IF;
END $$
```

The error coming up states:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00 AND new.lesson_time < 08:00:00

Sorted this myself now! Thank for the help?????

Comment: You need the time values inside single quote.

Comment: Thanks Abhik this seems to have moved the error to the SET MSG so I've taken the message out for now, however the new error is:        #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 8

Comment: Just add this line below `begin`  `declare MSG varchar(255);`

Comment: Taking the message out now, the important part is the trigger itself so I want to get that done first.